# React Redux store being "overwritten" on an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, signalr

I'm running into a strange behavior where I have one object in state being completely removed when an action updates another. To explain:

I have this initial state:

```
logs: [],
simpleWifi: {
    thermostats: [],
    fetchedThermostats: []
},
workspace: {
    userWorkspaces: [],
    focusedWorkspace: { id: 1 } as Workspace
}
```

The initial state works fine, everything is present. However, when I (through signalR hub) get the user workspaces, focusedWorkspace gets removed from the state. I'm not sure why that exactly is, and why it's only removing this from the state?

I've defined a workspaceReducer which has:

```
const workspace: Workspaces = {
    userWorkspaces: [],
    focusedWorkspace: null
};
```

```
export const workspaceReducer: Reducer<Workspaces> = (state: Workspaces | undefined, incomingAction: Action): Workspaces => {
    if (state === undefined) {
        return workspace;
    }

    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type) {
        case "RECEIVE_ALL_USER_WORKSPACES":
            return {...state, userWorkspaces: action.workspaces };
        case "NEW_FOCUSED_WORKSPACE":
            return {...state, focusedWorkspace: action.focused };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

For some reason, when the RECEIVE_ALL_USER_WORKSPACES gets dispatched, focusedWorkspace gets undefined and then ultimately removed from the state completely (even the default value originally set).

EDIT1:
The SignalR hub dispatch is as follows with the ReceiveUserWorkspace being defined:

```
workspaceHub.on("ReceiveUserWorkspaces", (workspaces: Workspace[]) => {
        store.dispatch({ type: "RECEIVE_ALL_USER_WORKSPACES", workspaces } as ReceieveUserWorkspaces);
    });
```

```
export interface ReceieveUserWorkspaces {
    type: "RECEIVE_ALL_USER_WORKSPACES",
    workspaces: Workspace[]
}
```

The workspace list:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Global",
    "category": "Global",
    "userID": null,
    "thermostats": []
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Test",
    "category": "Test",
    "userID": "asdf",
    "thermostats": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `RECEIVE_ALL_USER_WORKSPACES` action object when it's dispatched?

Comment: @markerikson edited into the question